# What features do you look for in an Enterprise Log Management solution? 

Tags: network, windows, linux, logging, siem

This question is for IT Pros, and people who manage a company's infrastructure. [Developers should see this related answer for tools geared for them.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776691/328397)

What are your requirements for such a Event Log Managment solution?  What do you currently, or do you hope to derive from such a system?

**More info:**

I found [a related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/361/396) that focuses on how an *application* should save to the eventlog, but this question is orthogonal to that.  Here I'd like to what tools, reports, and surrounding alerts you want from a system that aggregates, and analyzes log files.

In an Enterprise setting this would undoubtedly include: Windows Event Logs, Firewall, Router logs, syslog, etc.

Comment: 7, according to your update, are you specifically looking to *exclude* application logs (the aggregation thereof, NOT *how/what to log*)? Because a SIEM that ignores that, is pretty much useless (or close to that) - lowlevel network/OS data without the logical information from the application is way to obtuse to glean any real conclusions.

Comment: Maybe I should update again... I want to include the application logs from systems across my Enterprise.  I also want to centralize the monitoring and utility of the logs from a central point.  My intent is to gain value from whatever information the proprietary application chooses to log.

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it is not relevant to the question anymore

Comment: Big Brother http://bb4.com/ is a great example of such an enterprise network monitoring tool.

Comment: Can you elaborate and tell us why it is a great tool?  What features or functionality did you discover?/

Comment: You may want to add "User Experience Monitoring" to this list. Its a new area, but vital for effective system monitoring. You can have all the disk, ram, processors you want, but if it still takes 10 minues to logon, or 5 minutes top open a word processor then other info is sort of irrelavent..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are a few different features you should consider, note that you might not need all of these, and one might not be better than the other - but they are points to consider:

- Coverage:

  - Windows Event Log on servers, all current versions
  - Windows Event Log on clients, all versions in your org (you'd be surprised how many Win98s there still are...)
  - syslog on Linux/Unix servers according to your flavors
  - syslog on Linux/Unix workstations (if you have) according to common flavors in use
  - generic SNMP traps
  - Other OSs you might have...
  - Network equipment (if thats where you want to take it): Firewalls, routers, gateways, proxies, WAFs, IDS/IPS, etc
  - Web/App server logs: e.g. IIS, Apache, WebSphere, WebLogic, etc, whatever else you have
  - Databases
  - Mail servers
  - MQ servers if you have them and they are critical
  - AD/directory/IdM servers
  - security and control servers, e.g. content filtering gateway, HPOV, MS SMS, etc.
  - etc any other infrastructure you find critical
  - Application logs! As I said in my comment up top, this are of critical importance, yet are most often neglected. While there is no real common format (there are some structures but nothing data-specific), the SIEM product/solution should:
    a. be able to receive and generically parse a variety of formats and files, e.g. CSV, XML, flatfiles, etc.
    b. ideally would be able to define specific formats and recognize the data
- Agent vs agentless (aka push vs. pull)

  - There are advantages to each, which is better really depends on your specific environment.
  - Best would be support of both models, and use each where appropriate
  - Even bester is support of a builtin API to log directly to it.
- Aggregation and consolidation
- Correlation - i.e. link different events from different sources together to form a single meaningful incident. Ideally should use a variety of techniques
- Reporting and dashboards - should be BI-like, both for trend analysis and specific incident/user investigation
- Automated analysis and active alerting, depending on configuration. Should be flexible enough to fit your needs and expectations. Analytical engines should be able to identify certain classes of misuse/fraud/attacks in (near-)real time.
- Historical data, and reports/analysis/correlation over time
- If its relevant, some products offer "Compliance" packages, to assist in meeting specific regulatory requirements.
- high availability
- Ample protection of log data, both its confidentiality and its integrity, using combination of encryption, access control, self-logging, etc.
- Remote management (securely, of course)
- Possibility to plug into SOC if/when you get there

Comment: Holy feature set Batman!  +1 ...this will take time to digest; however I think that you will probably add to this over time and I'll be very interested if/when you do.

Comment: :D, yup, I admit that I did not spend a ton of time ensuring this is complete, however these are things I've been thinking about / working on. A caveat, I find it doubtful that you will find a perfect solution with full coverage of all these features. As I said, these are some of the main points to consider, then do your own tradeoff of whats most important to you, according to your own environment and risk analysis.

Comment: Very nice list.  As an addendum, look *very* closely at log source support.  We got burned with our purchase a few years ago because of how overstated their Windows Server 2008 support really was.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out Anton Chuvakin's [Log Management Buyer Checklist](http://chuvakin.blogspot.com/2010/11/log-management-tool-selection-checklist.html)

Comment: Yup, Anton is pretty much one of the biggest authorities on this.